# good tutorial and training material for ajax forms in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal-7

I'm having some trouble to make an ajax-form work with drupal 7.

Besides the examples located in:
http://drupal.org/node/262422

can anyone suggest a good tutorial just for ajax-form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

Looking for good tutorials and examples about ajax-form in drupal 7, i've found the following links:

1. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ -> forum about drupal in the same style of stack overflow;
2. http://drupal.org/node/1043838 -> drupal examples
3. http://buildamodule.com/ -> a lot of videos about drupal (has some paid content, but also has free streaming videos)